# Airbus Beluga, what is aft of the cockpit?

Tags: airbus-beluga

In the Airbus Beluga (and Beluga XL), the main cargo deck runs the full length of the aircraft, starting just above the cockpit. Is there more usable space behind the cockpit? Or are there fuel tanks here?

In the attached image of a Beluga, there appears to be large door immediatly forwards of the tailnumber, and a smaller door aft.

[image]

Image taken from [Airbus Beluga promo site](https://www.airbus.com/aircraft/freighter/beluga.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the Beluga, the [area behind the cockpit bulkhead 6 is unpressurized](https://www.flightglobal.com/pdfarchive/view/1994/1994%20-%201288.html). It contains avionics (A19), the nose wheel and the crew entry hatch (17). It is connected to the forward underfloor cargo bay. That area is unchanged from the A300: it's where the passenger luggage is usually kept. Aft of the wing is another cargo bay.

The same goes for the Beluga XL: underneath the floor, it's identical to a normal A330.

[image]

This [article indicates](https://samchui.com/2019/02/18/airbus-to-build-sixth-beluga-xl-and-sell-old-belugas/) the underfloor cargo areas can be used:

> ... the Beluga XL can carry two A350 wings with additional space for other small components and cargo pallets underneath the main hold floor.
>
> Underneath the freight area is room for 14 LD3 containers as well as a bulk cargo compartment in the far aft.

Comment: Thanks, however, I was meaning running the full length behind the cockpit, and below the main cargo deck. According to the sketch you provided, those doors are part 44. These are are labelled "Access doors to cargo bay". I think you called this "the forward underfloor cargo area".  So is this a second cargo bay?